# python-docx - replacing characters

Tags: python, text, docx, python-docx

I am trying to build a small program in which I open a docx document and replace characters by others, to do some old school caesar-style encrypting, after checking the documentation: [ https://python-docx.readthedocs.io ] I am afraid I can't find the object methods and attributes, the documentation just kind-of explains how to do certain stuff like creating paragraphs and sections but I can't find anything on retrieving document data and parsing. I would like to find a list of the objects in the document so I can parse through them.

I would like to do something like this:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('essay.docx')

paragraph = []
for i in document:
    paragraph.append(i)

for i in paragraph:
    for y in i:
        y.replace("a", "y")

...
```

Can python-docx do something like this? If so where would I find the documentation that could show me how to do it?

If maybe I am using the incorrect library I would also appreciate it if you could point it out.

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation is indexed (i.e. its table of contents appears) on the page you link to and describes all the objects and methods. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api-documentation

Comment: Yeah I read those pages too and I found methods such as "add_paragraph()" and "add_run()" but I could not find methods like "get_paragraph()". I need to get objects to parse through and modify to make a new file. Maybe this library only works for creating docx documents but not for retrieving data from them?

Comment: Look in the Document object. I think you're looking for `Document.paragraphs`.

Comment: It seems too hacky to be an answer, but you can actually unzip Word documents and it returns, among other things, a text document with the unformatted text. I'm not familiar with this library, but if worse comes to worst you could use one utility to unzip it, then read the text, delete the unneeded parts, then use this library to build the document you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something useful in case future readers might be interested. The problem with python-docx is I could get paragraphs individually and it would take a lot of time. I don't even know if titles, footers and headers count as paragraphs.

But there is a library called textract that can read docx and other files, it integrates with python-docx, or at least that's what the short documentation says. But what I can do, is save my docx file to PDF and use:

```
text = textract.process(
    'path/to/norwegian.pdf',
    method='pdftofile',
    language='nor',
)
```

This allows you to get all the text as a string and save it preserving the layout of the pdf. Haven't tested it yet, will edit this post if it doesn't work as intended.

http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_package.html#python-package